# Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_result() on boolean

Tags: php

```
<?php

require "conn.php";

$GroupName = "test";
$sql_query ="SELECT G_number FROM Group WHERE Group_Name like '$GroupName';";
$row = mysqli_query($conn,$sql_query);
$result = $row->get_result(); //error comes up here




$sql_query2 =$conn->prepare("SELECT Question, User_name,date FROM Post WHERE Group_number = '$result';");
$sql_query2->execute();
$sql_query2->bind_result($Question,$User_name,$date);

$post = array();

while($sql_query2->fetch()){

$temp = array();
$temp['Question'] = $Question;
$temp['User_Name'] = $User_name;
$temp['Date'] = $date;

array_push($post,$temp);



}
echo json_encode($post);
?>
```

I am trying to get the json to print out to the html when I put the domain in the url, but I constantly get this error in my logs:

> " PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function
>   get_result() on boolean in
>   /home/f7215owv4qzh/public_html/post_retrieval.php:8"

Does anyone have any idea of what I am doing wrong? I have searched for a fix and changed the syntax to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
$result = $row->fetch_array();
```

**OR**

```
$result =mysqli_fetch_array($row)
```

Comment: as to replace line 8, place it before, or to place it after?